# Distance in Meters/Kilometers from pgr_drivingdistance

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, driving

I am having trouble calculating distance (driving distance) along a route with the pgr_drivingdistance function. I have a straightforward workflow, I download OSM data, and put that into postgresql with osm2pgrouting, and am trying to calculate a route between two nodes. I just want the distance for that route. This is my query:

```
select sum(cost) from pgr_drivingdistance('select gid as id, source, target, cost from ways', 84216, 84216, true);
```

I know cost is not the distance, but when I try to pass `length_m` as `cost`, I don't get the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong function; `pgr_drivingDistance` returns **a table of all nodes that can be reached within the given `distance` value**, e.g. the 'catchment'!

If a **shortest path between two nodes** is what you are after, you likely want to use [`pgr_dijkstra`](https://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/pgr_dijkstra.html), or the aggregate version [`pgr_dijkstraCost`](https://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/pgr_dijkstraCost.html) (there is the similar [set of functions](https://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/aStar-family.html) using the *A* * algorithm, too).

For getting the total distance of the (shortest) path in *metric units*, you will either have `cost` values in a *metric unit* (pre-calculated or by using data in a projected CRS), or post-process the results to do so, e.g.

- if your `cost` values are supposed to be **the length of the `ways` geometries**, run

  ```
  SELECT agg_cost
  FROM   pgr_dijkstraCost(
           'SELECT gid AS id, source, target, ST_Length(<geom>[::GEOGRAPHY]) AS cost FROM ways',
           <source_node_id>,
           <target_node_id>
         )
  ;
  ```

  where the optional cast to `GEOGRAPHY` will result in the `cost` values to be in *meter* **if the geometries are referenced in a geographical CRS**
- if your `cost` values are **other pre-computed weights**, run

  ```
  SELECT SUM(ST_Length(ways.geom[::GEOGRAPHY])) AS dist
  FROM   pgr_dijkstra(
           'SELECT gid AS id, source, target, cost) AS cost FROM ways',
           <source_node_id>,
           <target_node_id>
         ) AS routed
  JOIN   ways
    ON   routed.edge = ways.gid
  ;
  ```

  where you `JOIN` the resulting path back to the `ways` table to get the respective geometries and their `ST_Length`, again with the optional cast to `GEOGRAPHY`as above

About these examples: if your `cost` value represents the edge length in a *metric unit* already, there is obviously no need to recompute them within the function. However, if that length is directly derived from the *geographical* length (*degrees*), you will need to run one of these examples, as plain *degree* measures are useless by themselves without context.

Comment: This worked! `cost` was distance in degree units, so I used sum(st_length). Thanks for the answer.